# Poor Wifi Signal Strength on Dell Latitude Laptop with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, dell, iwlwifi

Wifi signal strength is moderate at 3 meters from the router with no obstacles in the middle. The signal strength reduces if I move to 5 meters; and if I move to the next room, wifi disconnects. This laptop did not have a wifi problem with Windows installed. The Dell latitude laptop has Ubuntu 20.04. I tried setting the `ant_sel` to `1` for iwlwifi and that did not help. The laptop uses Intel 3165 for wireless interface.

````
$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 3165
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       logical name: wlp6s0
       version: 79
       serial: 70:1c:e7:16:c2:cc
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.4.0-42-generic firmware=29.1654887522.0 ip=192.168.1.112 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:50 memory:f7100000-f7101fff```
````

#Link Quality at 3 Meters:

```
$ iwconfig
wlp6s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"swshaabsnl"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.417 GHz  Access Point: 34:E8:94:53:E9:48   
          Bit Rate=21.7 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=19/70  Signal level=-91 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:49   Missed beacon:0

$ uname -av
Linux aniruddha-Latitude-3560 5.4.0-42-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 10 00:24:02 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Thanks for your help!

Edit 1:

```
$ modinfo iwlwifi
filename:       /lib/modules/5.4.0-42-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
<...............snip..............>
parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int)
parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint)
parm:           amsdu_size:amsdu size 0: 12K for multi Rx queue devices, 2K for AX210 devices, 4K for other devices 1:4K 2:8K 3:12K 4: 2K (default 0) (int)
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool)
parm:           antenna_coupling:specify antenna coupling in dB (default: 0 dB) (int)
parm:           nvm_file:NVM file name (charp)
parm:           lar_disable:disable LAR functionality (default: N) (bool)
parm:           uapsd_disable:disable U-APSD functionality bitmap 1: BSS 2: P2P Client (default: 3) (uint)
parm:           enable_ini:Enable debug INI TLV FW debug infrastructure (default: 0 (bool)
parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool)
parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off (default: 0) (int)
parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)
parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)
parm:           fw_monitor:firmware monitor - to debug FW (default: false - needs lots of memory) (bool)
parm:           disable_11ac:Disable VHT capabilities (default: false) (bool)
parm:           remove_when_gone:Remove dev from PCIe bus if it is deemed inaccessible (default: false) (bool)
parm:           disable_11ax:Disable HE capabilities (default: false) (bool)
```

Comment: "tried setting the ant_sel to 1 for iwlwifi and that did not help." That's because ant_sel is not an available module parameter for your driver. Please check: `modinfo iwlwifi | grep parm` Are you quite certain that both antenna wires are firmly snapped in place? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I looked for the antenna wires. According to Dell, they pass through the hinges and into the top via sides. I could not open the laptop to locate the antenna, but since there is no physical damage let's assume that the antenna is alright. I have edited the problem description to add parameters listed by modinfo. Would it be useful to change any parameters from the default value?